# create a multilevel array from a single array

Tags: php, arrays, transform, multi-level

I want to convert an existing array structure to create a parent / child array. A div nesting should then be generated from this.

These are the values that I have to process.

```php
$arr [10] = array ('type' => 'div');
    $arr [20] = array ('type' => 'div' );
        $arr [30] = array ('type' => 'div');
        $arr [] = array ('type' => 'div_close');
        $arr [40] = array ('type' => 'div');
        $arr [] = array ('type' => 'div_close');
    $arr [] = array ('type' => 'div_close');
$arr [] = array ('type' => 'div_close');
```

I want this result:

```php
$arr[10] = array(20);
$arr[20] = array(30,40);
```

My idea was to create a foreach loop and assign the values to the respective arrays.
Unfortunately I can't get any further and hope for help.

Comment: Welcome Martin, can you add your existing code to your question so the users can check where you are stucked?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The approach you follow won't work. Regardless of whether it is a good idea or not to try to "meta describe" your markup in such way you will find that the starting sequence you try to setup with the given array definitions you posted does _not_ create an array as you would expect it. `$arr[]` will not be at the position you apparently expect it to be.